# how to convert cocos2d project to cocos2d-box2d project?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I created a project based on cocos2d,and now I want to convert to cocos2d-box2d project. What should I do? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're asking this question I believe it will be the easiest solution for you to create a new Cocos2D project based on the Box2D template, then add your existing project's source code and resource files to the new project. You will have to rename all implementation files from .m to .mm as well, to avoid compiler errors. This is necessary because Box2D is written in C++.